# How to mark environments in tags?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Should we introduce { and } in tags, if it's possible, technically?

It would be useful to mark environments, like {itemize}, {center}, {table}. We could distinguish {table} environment questions from such regarding tables like tabular constructs.

Would it be meaningful to see when a tag means an environment (center, quotation, quote) instead of a concept (centering, quoting)?

As some other questions show, I'm thinking about a clear understanding if a tag means a concept, class, package, environment or command - a lot of names are very similar. I made separate questions because a feature request like \ in tags is different than just to agree in tag names like [book-class] or discussing how environments should be handled.

Another drastic way would be tagging like book-cls, cite-pkg, center-env, cite-cmd, ...

Any other ideas or sugegstions?

Comment: Tag characters: a-z 0-9 + # - .

Comment: Developers could extend that if they were convinced or charged with.

Comment: Although I like the idea of \tags and kind of agree with book-class, this one I think is too much. Do we really need to distinguish all of these at the tag level?

Comment: Not necessarily. The idea came with the question how to see wether a tag name means a concept or it's a code word/ control sequence.

Comment: It looks like { and } in tags is now out of the question -- it would conflict badly with the way tags are displayed in the new style.

Comment: @SamB: That's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{..}` would be a Good Thing if it worked, although I don't particularly care about well-typed tags: do we really care about distinguishing questions that use the tag matching the package `alltt` from the questions that use the tag matching the environment `alltt`?  Generally, we don't need the kind of indexing scheme that make librarians happy, but having `{..}` available, perhaps for both packages and environments, would be useful.

I think the question should be asked on meta.SO about possible issues with `{..}` tags.  The dev team might be planning to use {} in search operators, for all we know.

Comment: I think we should discuss first whether the feature makes sense and, as a community, we like it, before even thinking about technical issues or getting the developers involved.

Comment: With the current design, `{` in tags would look rather strange.

Answer (score 2):

An idea, which doesn't touch input, handling or links of tags would be just a visual tag shape. I introduced the idea in [Backslash in tags](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/backslash-in-tags).

That means, environment tags have `{    }` on the tag symbol, command tags have a `\` written before the command name. Does it seem too strange?

The first idea came because commands without backslash look really strange to me. Besides commands, all other code-tags concern environments I guess. So, we would get correct commands on tags and even further all code tags (\centering, center-environment, \draw etc.) are distinguished from concept-tags (centering, drawing). packages names may remain like normal tags.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be meaningful to see when a tag means an environment (center, quotation, quote) instead of a concept (centering, quoting)?

Yes, absolutely – but I think the separation is already clear. Consider your example: `center` vs. centering, `quote` vs. quoting, etc.

Furthermore, there’s the convention of using plurals where it helps, e.g. “tables” vs. `table` etc. This should probably go in the FAQ.