# {graphics}, {figures} & friends: Do we need all of them?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Assuming the retagging proposal regarding [{floats}, {tables} and {figures}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/contradictory-tag-wiki-entries-floats-tables-figures) is implemented, questions about the `figure` environment should be tagged with [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats). This begs the question what (if any) area of application remains for the [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) tag.

The graphics-related tag with the most questions attached to it is [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). Its [wiki entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/graphics/info) says: "Use the {graphics} tag for general questions regarding inclusion of graphical material in your document, usually from an external file. If you'd like to discuss vector graphics created programmatically inside a TeX document, use the general {diagrams} tag, or preferably the tag for the vector graphics package you use (e.g. {tikz-pgf} or {pstricks})."

[graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), [tikz-pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pdf) and [pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks) seem like good choices to me. On the other hand, I noticed that while the [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) tag features 27 questions at the moment, only one of them is also tagged with [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). I take that as a hint that [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) is rather used as a synonym for [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and could be merged with it.

Then there's the [picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture) tag (14 questions). There's [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) -- 86 questions at the moment, but prone to twindle because of the upcoming retaggings to [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats). And there may be even more graphics-related tags I've overlooked.

Please provide input as to which graphics-related tags you view as essential, and which as dispensible.

Comment: Do you have a plan, how to coordinate the retagging effort? Should different people work on different tags?

Comment: @Caramdir: First, let's wait a day or so if another answer is added that differs significantly from @Martin's. If not, I suggest that one person (me/you?) sorts through the {figures} and {picture} tag, and another person (you/me?) inspects the {tables} tag (which is bulkier, but hopefully less in need of retagging). A third person (with moderator powers) could be responsible for merging and creating tag synonyms.

Comment: @Caramdir: And it goes without saying -- flooding the starting page is to be avoided.

Comment: @Caramdir: Last, but not least: With the start of our retagging effort, the tag wiki entry for {floats} should be replaced by the one proposed [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/contradictory-tag-wiki-entries-floats-tables-figures/1019#1019). No need to produce new improper taggings while we correct old ones.

Comment: This has come up several times, first by [Martin](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407/merging-figures-and-diagrams) then later by [me](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689/graphics-images-tags). Happy to see something going ahead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture) - <strike>unnecessary, can be removed from basically all questions without loss of context</strike>  removed.
- [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) - <strike>synonym to {floats}</strike> EDIT by lockstep: Questions tagged with [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) will be retagged manually.
- [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) - keep
- [drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) - <strike>seems redundant mostly, but could be made a synonym to  {diagrams}</strike> removed.
- [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) - <strike>not very familiar with this, but seems that {tikz-pgf} should cover this already.</strike> Apparently this tag has a  merit of its own, so it should stay as it is.
- [subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfloat), [subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfigure) - merged, possibly with a new name [subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfloats) ✔
- [includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/includegraphics) - <strike>synonym to {graphics}</strike> removed.
- [graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphicx) - <strike>synonym to {graphics}</strike> removed.

I do not agree that the taggers use [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) as a synonym to [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) -- for me the fact they are not used together is that askers and taggers feel they are covering different grounds. The questions currently marked [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) are usually in the form of "How to create `<diagram-type>`?". For me, these are conceptually different from what is cover by [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) by virtue of the method they are being created (programmed by a macro language inline vs. inserted from an external image).

Comment: I agree, except that I think pgfplots should be kept separate. It is used often enough and sufficiently different from pure TikZ/PGF that it warrants a tag of its own.

Comment: I too begin to see virtue in {diagrams}. And I really like the suggestion about a {subfloats} tag.

Comment: Skimming the questions tagged with {picture}, I think they should be retagged manually (but there are only about a dozen).

Comment: @lockstep: You already have experience with mass manual retagging, so that shouldn't be a problem for you :-)

Comment: @lockstep: Well, there is no tool to just remove a tag, so they'd have to be done by hand in any case.

Comment: ok, I destroyed the `picture` tag since that seemed particularly low-value. there is one question tagged `untagged` now though.

Comment: Question formerly tagged {untagged} now features the {diagrams} tag.

Answer (score 3):

I ask a moderator to do the following:

- Make [drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) a synonym of [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams); ✔
- Merge [subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfloat) and [subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfigure) into a new tag {subfloats}; ✔
- Make [includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/includegraphics) and [graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphicx) a synonym of [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics). ✔

The [figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) and [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tags will be retagged manually within the next few weeks.

Comment: Should [tag:tables] and [tag:tabular] be merged in the end?

Comment: @Caramdir: Good idea! I overlooked that {tabular} (unlike {tabularx} or {booktabs}) doesn't stand for a package name.

Comment: I have some thoughts to it, have a look at [my answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/graphics-figures-friends-do-we-need-all-of-them/1058#1058).

Answer (score 2):

I decided to use the form of an answer in response to [locksteps post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/graphics-figures-friends-do-we-need-all-of-them/1053#1053).

- My first check for [drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) showed that the questions are not only about diagrams but also about drawing shapes and the like.
- Merging is ok. However, subfigures don't necessarily have to float, imagine the `subcaption` package used with `minipage` environments. That's why I prefer the master tag [subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfigures) for the merge instead of [subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subfloats).
- This is mixing a command, a package and a concept together. I think it goes too far and takes us the possibility to distinguish grapics inclusion from graphics creation.

Comment: @Stefan: a) {drawing} Do you mean that some questions should be retagged, and some left alone? Are diagrams and drawings distinct enough to justify different tags? b) {subfigures} I defer to our opinion. c) I was under the impression that {graphics} is now about inclusion, and {diagrams} (or special tags like {tikz-pgf}) about creation. With that in mind, I'm still for the suggested synonyms.

Comment: @Stefan: The middle part should be "I defer to *your* opinion". (Freudian slip, anyone?)

Comment: @lockstep: a) Let's keep {drawing} for questions which are not about diagrams: drawing geometric objects and shapes and the like. {diagrams} feels just wrong for drawing a rectangle. b) Second thought, {subfloat} is ok also for me. It's consistent with {float}. `subcaption` without float may go to {caption} and {minipage} if needed-it's not a different concept. c) There's also rotation and resizing/scaling. `\includegraphics` belongs to the same package but is not synonym to that. If there's some doubt, we do not have to hurry.

Comment: @lockstep: I made {subfloats} a master tag and {subfloat} and {subfigure} to synonyms. {drawing} and {graphics} are still pending--still there's time for suggestions or actions.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks -- and let's take one`s time with drawings vs. diagrams (!).

Comment: @lockstep: {drawing} is already gone.