# {tables} and {tabular} tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tagwiki

I just made a tag-wiki for [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular) without realising that there is a very similar one for [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables).  Should these be merged or one made into a synonym of the other (are these independent?).  I had assumed that [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) was about floating tables, but now I realise that there was discussion here: [Contradictory tag wiki entries: {floats}, {tables}, {figures}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/contradictory-tag-wiki-entries-floats-tables-figures) assumes otherwise, given the range of questions assoiated to the [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tag.

Comment: I am for merging, but only after I have finished cleaning up the {tables} tag (that will take a couple of days or maybe weeks to avoid flooding the front page).

Comment: I merged the two tag wiki entries, basically combining Stefans introduction and your list of table-related packages.

Comment: @lockstep Ok.  Thanks.  So the {tabular} tag will go away eventually?

Comment: Yes, it will become a synonym for {tables} *after* Caramdir has skimmed (and partially retagged) the questions now tagged with {tables}.

Answer (score 4):

I went through all the questions tagged [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) and retagged the appropriate ones with [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats) (or similar). Baring any questions that I might have overlooked, [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) and [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular) are ready to be merged.

Answer (score 4):

I approved [tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tabular) as synonym to the master tag [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) and merged it. Now we've got 190 [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) questions. Some questions have a duplicate [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) tag now, I asked Jeff to run the tag deduplication again.

Comment: Oh, that's great, no manual deduplication `:-)`